# Boot different drives

Tags: grub, disk, boot-loader

Is grub the only bootloader that can load an os on another disk than the one it is installed on?
Is grub the only bootloader that can do this, and boot an iso file (loopback)?

Answer (score 0):

No, [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can boot operating systems on any drive in the system, and can boot an operating system from an ISO image.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that one.  I shall give it a try.  Any others?

Comment: Probably, but none that I know of off the top of my head. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_bootloaders might help.

Comment: The 'file-system support' part of that wikipedia page is, I suppose, what the bootloader can read (thus load), not what it can run from.  I.e. grub2 supports exfat, but I land on the efi shell when I install grub2 on exfat, with no bootable disk listed.  Is it the bios/efi that determines what filesystems are supported to run the bootloader from?

Comment: BIOS doesn’t care about file systems; EFI only supports loading boot loaders from FAT. See https://jdebp.uk/FGA/pcat-boot-process.html and https://jdebp.uk/FGA/efi-boot-process.html for details.

Comment: So I've tried the refind boot manager (not loader).  Looks nice, but I can't find an option to boot an iso file (which is confirmed on 'https://superuser.com/questions/1597229/is-there-a-way-to-boot-from-iso-file-in-refind-boot-manager').

Comment: As mentioned there, you need to mount the ISO file in rEFInd, find the appropriate EFI executable and run it. This only works for ISO images which are bootable in EFI, not old El Torito images (which can’t be booted from EFI anyway).

Comment: How does one mount an iso file in refind?